# Use of Nav2 Stack and Commander API without AMCL , with just odometry data

Tags: ros2, nav2, visual-odometry

I want to test Nav2 for teach and repeat with just odometry data without building a map. Basically, I want to collect a series of waypoints indoors using odometry data and then start from same position and traverse the waypoints autonomously as a test case without worrying about obstacles and map (just want to test the nav2 controller and different waypoint behaviours). Is it possible to use the commander API for this or does it expect to have a map?
I am new to using nav2 and am not sure what changes to make to nav2_params.yaml file and if it requires a lot of changes. I have a vehicle equipped with a zed camera to record odometry. I just want to test simple waypoint following behaviours with recorded waypoints from zed and then using nav2 stack and odometry data from zed camera to repeat the same trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

Odometry will drift over time, so unless your teach-and-repeat-ing is happening in the same session (one after another) and relatively short, I don't think that's a viable solution. The robot will start to drift around after awhile without some kind of cached representation to try to match relationships against.

You will need some kind of consistent global frame to have this work repeatedly over longer periods of time, multiple times in a row, or over different sessions. VSLAM, Lidar SLAM, QR codes, and many other solutions exist for this as generic solutions. I suppose for a teach and repeat solution you could use something a bit more brute, but that would be pretty bespoke on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Visual teach-and-repeat is also called visual memory navigation. There are many research works on this topic.
The idea is go use a sequence of images as the reference, and rely on visual servoing. When the current image is close enough to the requested image, you change the latter to the next one from the visual memory. The robot never has to localize itself, only compute the self-motion required to approach the next image.

Note that this navigation approach has nothing to do with the nav stack that uses trajectory planning and tracking in SE(2), while visual memory is about tracking images.